# Which of these is a good way of expressing that the damage I caused to the three items occurred on a single occasion?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Which one(s) of the following is/are correct? And which one(s) would a native speaker use?

> a.   [when I found out he broke my window, I **got back at him three times as hard** by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera]
>
> b.   [when I found out he broke my window, I **paid him back with interest** by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera]
>
> c.    [when I found out he broke my window, I **got my back on him three times over** by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera]

What I am trying to say here is that the damage I caused to the three items occurred on a single occasion.

Answer (score 1):

I think those are all correct as a native english speaker. Since you are going with the notion of 3, you should exclude  b as it is not specific enough (still a valid phrase to use though).

You need a slight alteration to c though

c. [when I found out he broke my window, I **got back at** him three times over by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera]
Instead of "got my back on" it should be  "got back at".

Here is what I would say:

d.[when I found out he broke my window, I paid him back threefold by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera]

Comment: Hi, there, Cretting:[I got my back on him] was suggested to me by someone who was apparerntly from Britain.

Comment: I can't advise you as to British English, but **get my back on him** certainly does not mean what a and b mean in US English.

Comment: Isn't [I paid him back threefold] kind of old-fashioned? Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding 'get one's back on someone' https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/get-your-own-back-on-sb

Comment: @GrammarBoy I suppose it is a bit old fashioned, although not nearly as old fashioned as "thrice-fold". 'get one's back on someone'-> Would probably work in the UK, however in America you may get an odd look. Depends on where you are. I have never heard that phrase in America. On the page you sent me, the definition type they give is "uk informal" which would explain why I would never have heard about it.

Comment: @GrammarBoy - You have misread that. The phrase is, "to get your *own* back", not "to get your back".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your title correctly represents your question, none of your three suggestions (nor the suggestions in either of the existing answers) work. Your title says that you want to convey the idea that you broke all three items on one occasion. None of the suggestions contain anything that indicates that this is the case.

In your first example, "I got back at him three times as hard" only tells us that the damage that you inflicted was three times harder than the damage that he inflicted. There's nothing in the sentence that tells me that you didn't break each item on separate occasions.

In your second example, "I paid him back with interest" only tells us that what you did to him was *more* than what he did to you. It doesn't tell us whether you broke all three objects on one occasion, and unlike your first option it doesn't even tell us *how much* more you did to him than he did to you. For instance the broken window might have  been $100, while the broken bike, cellphone, and camera might have been only $50 each. So while you might have broken three times as many items as he did, you only caused him 1.5 times as much damage as he caused you.

In your third example, "I got my back on him three times over" also means that you did to him three times what he did to you. (Though it should probably be rewritten as "I got back at him three times over".) Like the first two examples, there is nothing in the sentence to indicate the number of occasions.

If you want to convey the idea that you broke all three items on the same occasion, you need to add something to the sentence that tells us that. There are various different phrases you can add.

You can simply state it explicitly:

> I broke his bike, cellphone, and camera all on one occasion.

Or you can use a phrase that won't be as clumsy:

> I broke his bike, cellphone, and camera in one fit of revenge.

Or:

> I broke his bike, cellphone, and camera in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

> c. [when I found out he broke my window, I got **my back on him** three times over by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera]  ***(Incorrect)***

when I found out he broke my window, I got my **own back** three times over by breaking his bike, cellphone, and camera  **(Correct)**